# Как из .java сделать .class?

Tags: java, eclipse

Я декомпилировал плагин в одной игре, изменил в нем пару слов и он стал формата .java.

Как мне его скомпилировать обратно в формат .class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296249/how-to-convert-java-file-to-a-class-file

Comment: Не работает( пишу C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\Levels.java ) мне пишет error: invalid flag: C:\Program
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

пишу javac Levels.java и так же

Comment: Блин, я не знаю как там там у вас в полуконсоле на винде это делать. Попробуйте открыть --help

Answer (score 1):

`java` - это файл, в нем может быть написано что угодно.
`class` - это **скомпилированный** файл.

Для компиляции используйте IDE. Если нет таковой - установите jdk нужной версии. Затем, если файл у вас один, используйте:

`javac name.java`

Comment: javac: file not found: Levels.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Comment: @Over_Ghost Нужно указывать правильный путь до файла, а не просто написать его имя.

Comment: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Levels.java:93: error: package Main does not exist
                Main.econ.withdrawPlayer((OfflinePlayer)p, 100000.0);
                    ^
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Levels.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
                final PermissionUser pm = PermissionsEx.getUser(p);
                      ^
  symbol:   class PermissionUser
  location: class Levels
100 errors
Получилось после javac C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Levels.java
До ошибок плевать главное где этот файл сохранился? :D

Comment: да скачай netbeans и не пудри мозги людям

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать только JAVAC, то так

Чтобы скомпилировать написанный нами код. Для этого используется утилита javac, которая поставляется вместе с jdk. Выполним эту команду в той папке, где лежат наши файлы :

```
 javac -d . *.java
```

Опция -d указывает, какие именно файлы мы хотим скомпилировать.

[Взял от сюда](https://devmark.ru/article/manual-java-compiling) ,тут всё подробно исписано.

Но лучше использовать, Или Maven или Gradle‎. Maven сейчас musthave

Comment: Вот что говорит подсказка: `javac -help`: `-d <directory> Specify where to place generated class files`. Не совсем  совпадает с тем, что вы указали в ответе.

Comment: @0xdb , я указал конкретную реализацию. Тк. человек сказал , "я не программист и никакого отношения к этому не имею". Не могу понять, что конкретно не совпадает ?(Приму критику)

Comment: Что конкретно не совпадает? Ваше, цитирую: _Опция -d указывает, какие именно файлы мы хотим скомпилировать_, и  то, что я привёл в комментарии выше.

Answer (score -1):

Окей, у тебя должна быть установлена JDK и прописан путь в path. Дальше все просто:

1. заходишь в папку где лежит java файл
2. shift+правая клавиша мыши - выбрать пункт открыть powershell (еще
   может про командную строку быть) Нам главное открыть cmd в папке где
   у тебя файл. В принципе можешь сделать это win+r-cmd-cd путь до
   папки с файлом.
3. когда ты в папке пиши javac test.java где test.java - название
   твоего файла. Класс в файле должен совпадать с названием файла. Т.е.
   "test" != "Test". Как у тебя внутри класс назван так и должен
   называться файл.
4. На выходе получите в папке .class файл.